# update existing move_uploaded_file code to handle an array instead of a single image upload

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have extended functionality of banner manager to allow for it to be multi language. This gives the user the opportunity to have language specific title, html banner, or image banner.

All the data is correctly being saved to the database now, but I can only ever get the first image of the three to be uploaded to the specified directory.

The original two code lines that uploaded the images are

```
if (move_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $this->filename)) {
chmod($this->destination . $this->filename, $this->permissions);
```

I thought that changing it to the following word work, but it still only sends a single image.

```
$languages = zen_get_languages();
for ($i=0, $n = sizeof($languages); $i<$n; $i++) {
$language_id = $languages[$i]['id'];
if (move_uploaded_file($this->file['tmp_name'][$language_id] , $this->destination . $this->filename[$language_id])) {
chmod($this->destination . $this->filename[$language_id], $this->permissions);
}
```

I can see that the correct data is available for the uploads from the following print_r commands

```
print_r($this->file['tmp_name']);
```

results in

```
Array ( [2] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpVr9JSd [1] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpGpYRG9 [4] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpfbOoQ4 )
```

and

```
print_r($this->destination);
```

results in

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/confetti/images/banners/
```

and

```
print_r($this->filename);
```

results in

```
Array ( [2] => stislide1.jpg [1] => stislide2.jpg [4] => stislide3.jpg )
```

You may be wondering why I made the assumption that putting [$language_id] into the move_uploaded_file command would work. That thought was based on the fact that the code I used to upload the correct path/name information to the database was

```
for ($i=0, $n = sizeof($languages); $i<$n; $i++) {
$language_id = $languages[$i]['id'];
$db_image_location = (zen_not_null($banners_image_local_array[$language_id])) ? $banners_image_local_array[$language_id] : $banners_image_target . $banners_image->filename[$language_id];
```

Obviously what works as part of the mysqli upload doesn't work in the class file where this upload function is added.

Any pointers on where I've gone wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to rewrite the code so that the array contents were handled by a foreach

```
foreach($this->file['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
  $file_name = $this->filename[$key];
  $file_tmp =$this->file['tmp_name'][$key];

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $this->destination. $file_name);
chmod($this->destination . $file_name, $this->permissions);
}
```

This is now uploading however many images are in the array